# Gitlab runner stop after npm install

Tags: yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci

For using the pipeline in Gitlab, i've created the following .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: node:8.2.1

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

TestIt:
  script:
    - npm install
    - '/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --single-run=true --browsers PhantomJS --watch=false'
```

When the runner start the job it is doing the npm install successfully but by that it ends. It doesn't continue to the second script (like it ignores it from some reason).

This is the output:

[image]

What can be the cause for that?

Comment: You are both referencing `node_modules` as relative and absolute paths ?

Comment: What happens when you remove the quotes around the command? Or put it in front of npm install just to test?

Comment: @StefanvanGastel the same result...

Comment: @GabrielBleu i'm referencing to that once in the cache and once when i need to activate the ng command

Comment: Your setup sounds very close to [this one](https://medium.com/letsboot/angular-4-and-testing-angular-cli-gitlab-ci-ng-test-phantomjs-tdd-afc20f50b928#12c6) but they are using `./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test`

Comment: @GabrielBleu even if I do like them it still give me the same result...

Comment: You can try to install it globally : `- npm install -g @angular/cli` then `- ng test` should work.

Comment: In the log you have `Using Shell executor...` but in the config you specify a docker image. You should see `Using Docker executor with image node:8.2.1 ...` in the log.

Comment: @GabrielBleu thanks, but it didn't worked..the same message as before is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still didn't found the reason why this happens but as A **workaround** After a long search instead of using `ng test`, i'm using `npm test`, like that:

```
TestIt:
  script:
    - npm test
```

in

*Karma.config.js*

I changed from `autoWatch: true` to `false` and from `singleRun: false` to `true` to prevent continuous testing.

I took out the  `- npm install`

Comment: This doesn't explain why. I have same problem with mvn command. Have you found more details since ?

Comment: I didn't find something new, just when I use the Git CMD or Git bash it does less errors

Answer (score 3):

If you are on windows, you probably ran into this problem (nothing else executing after a "npm" command):

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2730

TL;DR: Use `call npm install` instead of `npm install`, then the second command will execute too. Downside: Then your CI config is not platform-independent anymore.